# Why is before skip ignored in a tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, line-spacing

I have this MWE for a `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\blsn}[2]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        sharp corners, breakable, frame hidden, enhanced, boxrule=0pt, before skip=30pt, after skip=30pt,
        borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{red},
        segmentation style={red, line width=0.75pt, solid},
        colback=red!10,
        ]
        \textbf{Situation} \textit{(#1)}\\[2mm]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\secc}[1]{\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\section{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blsn{arg1}{arg2}
\blindtext

\section{Skip before ignored}
\blsn{arg1}{arg2}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The first one works as it should. But why is `skip before` ignored in the second one?

First box is ok:
[image: ok box]

Second box is not:
[image: not ok box]

Comment: I've taken the liberty to use your answer to edit your question to actually show the problem you're having.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you, I think the question now qualifies for being reopened.

Comment: @Teepeemm thank you for editing, but I guess your edit is already kind of the answer I was looking for.

Comment: But now that we've narrowed down the issue, someone may be able to explain how you could adjust `\secc` or `\blsn` so that they work the way you want.  (But what are you trying to achieve with `\secc`?  I'm not seeing how it's different than just using `\section`, which would solve your problem anyway.)

Comment: Thats a fair question. I tried a special section layout with ```titlesec```. In the upper part there is a line and i the lower part the title of the section. This splited over pages, when it was on the bottom of the page. There I needed that newcommand ```secc```. Now I just changed the layout of the title of the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tcolorbox.sty`, line 304 we have:

```
before skip balanced/.style={before={%
    \ifnum\lastnodetype=-1\relax%
    \else%
      \par%
      \ifvmode%
        \iftcb@minipage%
          \ifdim\parskip>\z@\relax%
            \addvspace{-\parskip}%
          \fi%
        \else%
          \ifdim\prevdepth<\z@\relax%
            \addvspace{\glueexpr#1-\parskip}%
          \else%
            \ifdim\prevdepth>.3\baselineskip\relax%
              \addvspace{\glueexpr#1-\parskip}%
            \else%
              \addvspace{\glueexpr#1+.3\baselineskip-\prevdepth-\parskip}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
        \fi%
        \nointerlineskip%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \lineskip\z@skip%
    \noindent%
  }},
```

I don't claim to understand everything but I see a test on vertical mode.

With `\leavevmode\par`, in the command `\bsn`, we obtain this `before skip` at the start of the page and also after the command `\section`

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705470/why-is-before-skip-ignored-in-a-tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}%<-- comment in the final document
\newcommand{\blsn}[2]{
    \leavevmode\par%<-- line added
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        sharp corners, breakable, frame hidden, enhanced, boxrule=0pt, before skip=30pt, after skip=30pt,
        borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{red},
        segmentation style={red, line width=0.75pt, solid},
        colback=red!10,
        ]
        \textbf{Situation} \textit{(#1)}\\[2mm]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\blsn{arg1}{arg2}
\blindtext

\section{Skip no more ignored}
\blsn{arg1}{arg2}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @montarenbici It's better with `\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer to my problem (even though I do not understand it). The problem appears if I use this command

`\newcommand{\secc}[1]{\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\section{#1}}}`

instead of `\section`

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer, but `\secc` does not appear in your question, so it's not clear to me why that would be a problem in your question.  Unless the code in your question doesn't show the problem that you're asking about, in which case, your question isn't all that great as a question.

Comment: I had a huge document and I had no clue where to find the error. For me, it is not clear, why my ```newcommand```, ```\secc```, is a problem. But anyway, I will avoid that in the futre.

Comment: Why on earth would you use such `\secc` command? It does nothing useful and breaks many things, in particular you can well have a page break between this title and the following text.

Comment: @egreg see my comment before

Comment: @montarenbici It explains nothing, sorry. XY-questions are very frequent and yours is quite certainly of the kind: instead of presenting the real problem you're facing with, you're telling how you tried to solve it (without telling what it is).